# Help debugging an Apex code to update the financial force SIN Lines

Tags: apex, error

I have this code that was provided to me by the Financial force support that shows how  the `DocumentAmendService` API Can Be Used to update the SIN Lines. Ran the code in the anonymous window in the dev console and this line is throwing an error: I am attaching a screenshot of the error.
[image]

I don't have much experience with Apex so I would really appreciate the help.

```java
List<c2g.CODAAPIInvoiceLineItemTypes_10_0.InvoiceLineItemForAmend> ListToAmend = new List<c2g.CODAAPIInvoiceLineItemTypes_10_0.InvoiceLineItemForAmend>();
List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoiceExpenseLineItem__c> ListSILines = new List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoiceExpenseLineItem__c>([select Id, c2g__Dimension2__c from
c2g__codaPurchaseInvoiceExpenseLineItem__c where c2g__PurchaseInvoice__c ='a7r6T000003464']);
for(c2g__codaPurchaseInvoiceExpenseLineItem__c SILine: ListSILines){
    c2g.CODAAPIInvoiceLineItemTypes_10_0.InvoiceLineItemForAmend amendDetail = new c2g.CODAAPIInvoiceLineItemTypes_10_0.InvoiceLineItemForAmend();
    amendDetail.InvoiceLineItem = c2g.CODAAPICommon.getRef(SILine.Id, 'http://siline.id/');
    amendDetail.Dimension2 = c2g.CODAAPICommon.getRef('a740A000001b7XXQAI', null);
    amendDetail.Dimension2specified = true;
    system.debug(amenddetail);
    listToAmend.add(amendDetail);
    if(!listToAmend.isEmpty())
    c2g.CODAAPISalesInvoice_10_0.BulkAmendInvoiceLineItem(null, ListToAmend);
}
```

Comment: I've adjusted the formatting of the code a bit to make it easier to read, but I've left in some things that are potentially syntax errors. On the first two lines, do you really have `newList` with no space between `new` and `List`? If so, that's another two syntax errors that you need to fix.

Comment: Thank you Derek, I actually don't have it like that in my code. I am not sure how to fix it in the post. Could you please fix that as well. thank you!

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix that (that's the same link that the "Edit" that appears under the body of your question goes to). You should take the [tour] and read through some of the [help] pages to become more familiar with this site. Text is also formatted [using Markdown](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thank you Derek. I will make sure I do the tour to learn how to best utilize the site.

Answer (score 1):

The [getRef](https://help.financialforce.com/accounting-api-apex/2022.3/CODAAPICommon.htm#getRef0) method takes two parameters, an Id and a String.

In other words, it should look like:

```
amendDetail.InvoiceLineItem = c2g.CODAAPICommon.getRef(SILine.Id, 'http://siline.id/');
```

This will get rid of the compile problems, though I'm not familiar with this method, so I'm not sure if the parameters are exactly correct. Please read the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, that did solve my first error but now I ran into another error. I attached the screenshot of the new error to the post.